# Uncle Roger Brings Joy to the World or a Type Harrassment?

Tags: united-kingdom, discrimination

Title refers, Uncle Roger is getting more famous recently by doing YouTube shows reviewing other chefs' cooking especially on Chinese Fried Rice.

> In July 2020, he went viral globally from his portrayal of “Uncle
> Roger”, a middle-aged Asian man reviewing an egg fried rice video. He
> has now amassed 136,116,860 views on his YouTube channel, 963k
> followers on Instagram and 94.7k followers on Twitter .
>
> In September 2020, he once again posted a critique video with regards
> to Gordon Ramsay's fried rice cooking, with him praising the latter
> for correct technique
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Ng

He got beaten up also during his fame on social media. Click for [source](https://www.thestar.com.my/lifestyle/entertainment/2020/11/01/malaysian-comedian-uncle-roger-says-he-was-a-victim-of-racial-attack-in-london?fbclid=IwAR36aHiLHsl2xSDGFnJbLhHgPJELAL7_vRWD8wlo0EL9TDyV-X5eu5gzLtg).

> "I… I don't know what I did," said Ng.

[image]

**1) Racial Harassment**
Commented Gorden is old and need to put the rice on the face as moisturizer, [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrUfwpaNNIM) At 4:33

Commented - A poor Indonesia get tortured by Gorden without proof. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrUfwpaNNIM) at 5.25

**2) Personal Harassment**

Same example on #1 consist the below

- Inappropriate comments
- Offensive jokes
- Personal humiliation
- Critical remarks

**3) Cyberbullying**

Make division of all of us and start attacking the [BBC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53me-ICi_f8) woman

[image]

[Reference](https://i-sight.com/resources/11-types-of-workplace-harassment-and-how-to-stop-them/?fbclid=IwAR1LBV3u_xHeKDOUQjcPztDIpVV-4caz7zW9-s6g9V9cl51rJ1RAAjjP5xI)

**Question )** Most of his shows consist of the elements below. Can other Youtubers actually sue him in UK?

Comment: Hi those voting down feel free to state a reason here ya.. Negative feedback welcome and i will not take it as harassment cause kinda learning and understand here :)

Comment: Haven't downvoted yet - but for me it's because basically none of your post text helps with your question. Your legal question seems to be whether Uncle Roger's behaviour amounts to harassment, but basically none of your post text helps in determining why you think that's the case. The one bit of info you included that might help is that he does reviews/critiques, but many people do that and it's not usually harassment so more info would be needed.

Comment: @DPenner1 i have edited my question ..let me know your view

Answer (score 1):

> Can other Youtubers actually sue him in UK?

Not really. I did not watch the entire first video, but freedom of expression protects the two excerpts you mention.

Suggesting a supposed remedy for skin moisturizing does not constitute racism. The Youtuber did not directly or indirectly refer to the man's race or ethnicity. If anything, the need for moisturizing has more to do with aging than with race. But either way the remark is not actionable.

The "torture" remark makes little or no sense, but the import of that remark would be protected as hyperbole, parody, or such. The remark would not impress on a reasonable person the idea that the cook resorted to torture, let alone for the sake of forcing someone to carry a stove. Accordingly, the cook is not defamed and the Youtuber does not need proof to support his remark.

Nor is there a "personal humiliation". No person could reasonably claim he or she was humiliated, in part because the Youtuber does not identify persons (such as the one who allegedly carried the stove).

Comment: The "torture" remark makes little or no sense --> he made a big font word that torturing an Indonesia, why not torture an American, British or Canadian... so racist wording.

Comment: Also, he humiliated the BBC woman face is stinky as the rice, then his follower keeps attacking on the comment section of the youtube

Comment: @Wayne97 "*why not torture an American, British or Canadian... so racist wording*". Are you suggesting that it is racist only if he mentions "Indonesian" but not if he says "American, British or Canadian"? By that token, wouldn't that suggestion make you a "racist"? Your misconception as to what constitutes racism can lead you to "see" a problem where there is none. For instance, the Youtuber is neither mocking Indonesians' physiognomy nor prejudicing against them whatsoever. I'm not watching the entire 2nd video, but the remark you describe does not seem actionable either.

Comment: i am reusing the Nigel Ng's word and tweak it to "American, British or Canadian" so it's a racist words then as well as "Indonesia". I agreed it is racist elements.

Comment: @Wayne97 "*I agreed it is racist elements*". It seemed to me that you were using a double standard, but now it is clear to me that you aren't. Regardless, a joke is not racist for merely mentioning the nationality of an actual or fictitious victim.